# Meaning of "Reverse my Polarity"

Tags: phrase-meaning, figurative-language

In Talking Tom and Friends, Season 1 Episode 5, "Magnetic Ben", when Ben became a magnet and got stuck to the garage door, he said to Angela:
"I need you to reverse my polarity!"
[image]
Immediately, Angela responded:
"That's disgusting!"
[image]
Which means "reverse my polarity" here must have a not-so-innocent meaning... I tried searching around, even on Urban Dictionary, but no websites mention this term at all. Does anyone know, or can anyone figure out the meaning of "Reverse my Polarity"?

Comment: In English almost anything can be a euphemism for sex, especially if you say it the right way.  See. e.g., Monty Python's "Nudge, Nudge" sketch.  In this case the joke is that she doesn't recognize the technical language so she just assumes it's suggestive.

Comment: Is that supposed to be a show for kids?

Comment: Yeah, it's a show for everyone, but this "reverse my polarity" is the only thing that confuses me because Angela said that was disgusting... it must have another meaning other than demagnetizing Ben...

Answer (score 1):

"Reverse the polarity" is a routine term in electronics meaning to switch the positive and negative poles. Like if you're running something off a battery, the battery will have positive and negative terminals. Switch the wires and you reverse the polarity.

Similarly, a magnet has north and south poles and something that causes these poles to flip reverses the polarity.

The example you cite is a joke. Magnetic Ben asks Angela to reverse his polarity as an attempt to get him to no longer be stuck to the wall. He means it literally. She interprets it as some sort of sexual comment or something else offensive.

I've never heard any sexual or controversial meaning for "reverse my polarity". Maybe this is used as a slag term used for some sexual act or something, but if so I've never heard of it. More likely the show is just making a joke, supposing that Angela THINKS is means something sexual when it doesn't. The writers probably do not have any specific sexual meaning in mind.